ffmpeg extraction with fixed color number
I need a hand in extracting images/frames from mpeg video with specified number of
colors, for example when I use identify verbose to see the number of colors

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
